# linear independent rows of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can reduce it to

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Do I have one linearly independent row here or zero independent rows?

Comment: "Linearly independent" is a concept for a **set** of vectors, not for individual vectors. It does not make sense to ask if a particular vector is independent or not.

Comment: really? You cannot say a single vector is independent of other vectors? i.e. not in the subspace of two other vectors for instance?

Comment: There are three vectors in the set.

Comment: Let $\{u,v,w\}$ be a set of vectors. I have never seen that people say "$v$ is an independent vector". While "$v$ is independent of $u$ and $w$" is understandable, I would rather say $v$ is not in the span of $u$ and $w$.

Comment: Well everyone is getting marked down by someone, so now I'm not confident I have a suitable answer yet.

Comment: Don't mind that. People tend to downvote without reason lately...

Comment: @Jack, are you retired? While you're there, is zero independent "rows" plural or not? You better look into it and correct it in case people misinterpret.

Comment: Sorry @Jack, thought you were voting me down for grammar. Downvote was for some other thing. Disregard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

First think about what it means to be linearly independent. Linearly independent means that every row/column **cannot** be represented by the other rows/columns. Hence it is independent in the matrix.

When you convert to *row reduced echelon form*, we look for "pivots".

Notice that in this case, you only have one pivot.

A pivot is the first non-zero entity in a row.

Here is your pivot:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore, since you only have one pivot, then two of your columns are **not** linearly independent, and one of them is. Therefore, we say that the $\dim(A)=1$, where $A$ is the matrix.

Comment: Yes, but does that mean the same for rows? I asked about rows. In this instance it might be that the rows and columns have the same number of independent vectors, but is that always the case? If not, shouldn't we be framing the answer in terms of rows, not columns?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say rows are independent. When you translate a matrix A into RREF, RREF = Reduced row echeolon form. The matrix A's rows are equivalent to the RREF's rows. The columns are not though

Comment: Ok, this book is saying that you can use columns instead of rows to state the definition of rank. So that would fit with what you're saying. But this book is also saying "linearly independent rows". Someone seems to think it makes sense to say "rows are independent". Thanks @KSplit

Answer (score -1):

Notice that a single vector, if it's not null, spans a a space. Notice also that "linearly independent" cannot be said to individual vectors.

Answer (score -2):

We say that the rows are not independant.

The space spanned by the rows has **dimension 1**.

Comment: Well i'm reading in a book that the rank of a matrix is equal to the maximum number of linearly independent rows or, equivalently, the dimension of the row space. So does that mean dimension of the rowspace, dim 1, and the number of linearly independent rows is equal?

Comment: Yes that's right ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich